# Any random variable is a function of a uniform?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, random

Is it true that:

"given a random variable $Z_i$ taking value in the Borel space $(\mathcal{Z}_i, \mathcal{B}_{\mathcal{Z}_i})$, there exists a function $l_i:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathcal{Z}_i$ such that $Z_i=l_i(\xi_i)$ with $\xi_i\overset{d}{\sim}  U([0,1])$. Moreover, $l_i$ is not unique."

Is this result obvious? Which assumption plays a crucial role?

Reading some sources, is instead the correct result
stating that $Z_i\sim l_i(\xi_i)$ in place of $Z_i= l_i(\xi_i)$ where $\sim$ denotes equivalence **in distribution**?

Comment: I haven't yet convinced myself/proven it for arbitrary Borel spaces; have you worked out what happens in the case where the Borel space is $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Actually, I am far away from proving things....  I am just trying to understand what is the key assumption here... I have found this statement for the first time here https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/networks/16-2/lectures/02/malik.pdf (claim 4 at p.7) but I couldn't find other sources with a proof on the web. Any hint on sources to look at would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: before doing generalization, maybe you first take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling

Comment: @BGM Thanks. The page you pointed out seems to suggest that $l_i$ could be the inverse of the cdf of $Z_i$. Correct? When this cannot be imposed?

Comment: @Bey how does non-existence of total ordering affect existence of $l_i$?

Comment: @STF I think I misread...$Z_i$ takes values in the reals, so its not relevant. I'll remove comment.

Comment: @BGM Actually, reading more carefully, the page you suggested says that $Z_i$ is distributed as $l_i(\xi_i)$ and not $Z_i=l_i(\xi_i)$. Is this the correct way to stating the result?

Comment: I am not an expert in mathematics so I have not studied so subtle things. My guess: for most usages people just care about how to transform the uniform random variable to their desired distribution. So equivalence in distribution is all they need. But of course they can be equal, no problem there. Just people not interested to talk about their dependency structure by saying $Z = l(\xi)$.